# Can I use both a Kolmogorov–Smirnov test and a T-test to compare two distributions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, p-value, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, reproducible-research

I have two distributions (N ~ 300, μ = 1.89 and σ = 0.97) and (N ~ 40, μ = 1.74 and σ = 1.18).

- A ks_2samp returns statistic = 0.2 and p-value = 0.057. Therefore, I cannot reject the null hypothesis that the two samples are identical.
- A ttest_ind returns statistic = 0.95 and p-value = 0.342. Therefore, I cannot reject the null hypothesis that the two samples have identical means.

My question is whether it's usual to report both tests comparing the distributions.

To put it in another way: In this case, does reporting more than one statistic is more effective to support the idea that these distributions are pretty similar?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What are you trying to do? I usually think that if you’re rooting for high p-values, you’ve made a mistake somewhere, and it sounds like you are rooting for high p-values.

Comment: Thank you, Dave. I'm just trying to compare the distributions. These are samples of dosages of a drug in the blood of males (N ~ 300) and females (N ~ 40).  To do a fair comparison, I have compared the distributions (ks-statistic) and their means (t-statistic). It seems that there is no statistically significant difference in the distributions between males and females. I wonder if it is statistically sound to report both of them.